# google drive folder information

Tags: google-drive-api, readonly

I would like to use Google Drive to push files in various folders onto a remote computer. I would like this to be a one-way transaction so the people using the computer cannot write to Google Drive.

However, when I use the following [C# code to get the files from Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#retrieving_a_list_of_collections) I only get the file names, not their directories where they will be on the remote computer. This won't work because some files in different directories have the same name. Is there a way to programmatically get directory information from these files?

Alternately, if I could set up the Google Drive folder to be read-only, that would accomplish my goal and probably be easier. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Google Drive API to [list all files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) and check the `parents` field of each of them to map those files into folders:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource

Comment: I finally got that working, but it took me forever to figure out that Google Drive API! Thanks